# How to check performance of a VM and the ESXi5 host?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

Are there any tools, or options (from VSphere client)  that I can try to find the memory and disk performance of an ESXi5 host and the VMs hosted on it ?

Comment: Did you not ready the documentation *at all*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the performance monitoring graphs provided by the vSphere client.

At the host level and the individual VM level, there's a "Performance" tab that provides some insight into the Disk, Memory, CPU, Network and other system metrics as real-time graphs. Using [vCenter centralized management](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-server/overview.html) will add historical metrics as well.

[image]

Comment: I knew about this option and exported it to a spreadsheet. My concern here  is the disk performance. The sheet on disk performance gives data, I am not sure if these are disk queue length (the values are not labeled I think and am not sure if these values and thresholds to compare performance with would be same as those in a windows server 2003/2008). Apologies, I should have been more clear in my first query.

Comment: I got the thresholds from the vSphere documentation. Thanks!